# How to set to default "S" and "s" vim plugin key mappings inside VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vim-plugin, keymapping

I tried deleting all shift+s and s keymaps that were default to VScode and it still didn't fix it.
Also there isn't another extension with the same key mappings.